# I am having trouble getting the Previous/Next Posts links to work on wordpress site

Tags: php, html, wordpress, hyperlink

I am building a wordpress site and created a blog page on a sub-page. Everything is working great except that I cannot get the previous/Next posts to work.

I am pretty new to PHP so may be way off here but have gotten everything else to work and just can't figure this out.

Thanks for any help!

Here is the PHP:

```
get_header(); ?>
<div id="background">
<div id="content">
        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div id="blogheader">
        <div id="logo"><img src="http://lynchbryan.com/clients/wp-content/themes/journalist/images/Wordmark-LBC_onwhite.s.png"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php
    $catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=4&posts_per_page=1' );
    while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
    ?>
    <div id="blog">
        <h3><?php the_title(); ?> | <span class="date"><?php the_time('F jS Y') ?></span></h3>

        <?php the_content(); ?> 
    </div>

    <div class="navigation"><p><?php posts_nav_link(); ?></p></div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>


</div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setup your pagination variable `$paged` above `catquery =`

`$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;`

then add this to your args inside `new WP_Query($args)`

so you can re-write it like this

```
$args = array('cat' => 4, 'paged' => $paged,'posts_per_page' => 1);
$catquery = new WP_Query($args);
```

then access your pages next and previous like so:

```
'<div>'.get_next_posts_link('Older', $catquery->max_num_pages).'</div>';
'<div>'.get_previous_posts_link('Newer', $catquery->max_num_pages).'</div>';
```